# React + Backbone application making 2 POSTS instead of 1

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, express, reactjs

I have a restful Todo List implemented with React and Backbone.

For now, I'm not talking to a database; just have an array `var mytodos = [];` in my server.js.
Here's the server code for POST (using Express):

```
app.post('/todos', function(req, res) {
    var todo = {
        id: mytodos.length,
        title: req.body.length,
        completed: req.body.completed         
    };

    mytodos.push(todo);
    console.log('POST ' + JSON.stringify(todo));
    res.send(todo);
});
```

When I add an item to the list, I see two POSTS being made for some reason.

```
POST: {"id":0,"title":"test","completed":false}
POST: {"id":1,"title":"test","completed":false}
```

In Chrome Dev. Mode, I see:

```
PUT localhost/todos/0 404 (Not Found)
PUT localhost/todos/1 404 (Not Found)
```

Two PUT requests!

Trying to reason through it - `save()` is called which calls `sync()`. Since the model doesn't have an `id` yet (only `cid`), it make a POST request and a todo (id = 0) is added to `mytodos` which then updates the model on the client (adds the `id` attribute). Since a change was detected, it does another `save()` which PUTS it to the server (<-- may very well be wrong here; not sure if the updated model would cause a PUT).

This might explain the PUT, but not the double POST.

Here is where `save()` is getting called (under `TodoApp = React.createClass...`:

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.props.todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate: ' + todo.id); // logs: undefined, 0, 1
        todo.save();
    });
},
...
save: function(todo, text) {
    console.log('Save: ' + todo.id); // only logged on update
    todo.save({title: text});
    this.setState({editing: null});
},
...
}
```

Why does this happen?
Why is it `PUT`ting in addition to `POST`ing? And why is it doing it twice?

**Edit:**
I resolved the double POST by changing `create` to `add` - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414714/backbone-sync-clarification/31435532#31435532) to where I got help.

The last problem is a `PUT 404 (Not Found)` for an item that is definitely on the server. Interestingly, the `PUT` is not going through my server it seems. My server only logs the `POST`. The `PUT` is being logged somewhere else.

Comment: We have faced similar issue and for us double server request issue was occurring, if view (or any object) is initialised twice (or more than once). You can put a debugger in chrome and see if it is hit twice. If you are initialising objects at a higher level (like in module) are you recreating the object in child view?

Comment: I think you'll need to show your React components that trigger the POST, your server code is not the problem.

Comment: Woops - looks like I accidentally deleted the latter half of this post. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the double POST by changing `create` to `add`

More specifically a certain event was triggering a `Backbone.Collection.create` call which according to [this](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) syncs with the server.

In my React code, I have a `componentDidUpdate` which calls `Backbone.Model.save` which also tries sending to the server. [Here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save).

Because the event caused both `create` and `save` to be executed, POST was firing twice.