# Backbone.sync clarification

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs, synchronization

After reading the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync), this is my understanding of `sync`.

I instantiate some `Backbone.Model` and call `Collection.create()`. `create()` eventually calls `sync()` and the `Model` is `POST`ed to the server. Then there is a `sync` in the opposite direction such that the `Model` on the client is given an `id`.

Does this update then trigger `componentDidUpdate()`?
*Note:* `componentDidUpdate` is a ReactJS thing, so if that doesn't make sense, the question reduces to "Is the client-side model updated and the view re-rendered?"

Since inside of my `componentDidUpdate()` I am making a call to `save()` to keep everything up to date, this subsequently makes a call to `sync()` which then fires a `PUT` request (because the `Model` already has an `id`).

I'm asking, because in my current application, creating a TodoItem seems to result in a `POST` and then a `PUT` which I find redundant. Perhaps it is for an unrelated reason.

It actually fires two POSTS and then two PUTS when adding one item, but that is another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you save a model (one which doesn't have an id) it will make a POST, thereafter it will make a PUT (update). I think you are confusing when to use `create`/`add`/`save`:

- Use `save` at any point to save the current client collection/model state to the server
- Use `add` to add Model(s) to a collection (a single Model, an array of Models, or an array of objects which contain attributes and let the collection create them)
- Use `create` as a shorthand for creating a model, adding it to the collection, and syncing the collection to the server.

My guess is that you are calling `create` and `save` in one operation - you should be using `add` and `save` instead, or just `create`.

The view will not automatically update for you, you will need to listen to changes or events on the collection/model and update the view yourself - there is no equivalent of `componentDidUpdate`. For example:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.onCollectionSync);
},

onCollectionSync: function() {
    this.render();
}
```

Comment: Great! Changing my `create` to an `add` took care of my double POST and PUT. Now, I'm just trying to figure out why after my POST, I get a PUT 404 Not Found on an item that is definitely on the server.